# UIPasteBoard in getting instantiated again and again in ios only happening in M1 Air

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to generate a device id and pasting it on pasteboard and the re using it.

```
    //Fetch 16 digit uuid
    let myPasteboard = UIPasteboard.init(name: UIPasteboard.Name(rawValue: "SFPboard"), create: false)
    
    if let uuid = myPasteboard?.string {
        return uuid
    }
    else {
        var uuid = NSNumber(value: 1 + arc4random_uniform(9)).stringValue
        var i = 0
        
        while i < 16 {
            uuid.append(NSNumber(value: arc4random_uniform(10)).stringValue)
            i += 1
        }
        
        let myPasteboard = UIPasteboard.init(name: UIPasteboard.Name(rawValue: "SFPboard"), create: true)
        myPasteboard?.string = uuid
        return uuid
    }
```

Comment: Since pasteboards like this aren't persistent across app launches, why not make it a singleton? Also, Apple's documentation states do NOT use that value to determine if the pasteboard has a string.. Use `hasStrings` property: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipasteboard/1622092-string

Comment: but this is only happening with M1 Macbook Air .....

Comment: not with intel pprocessor